# create a Python script which connects to a range of IPs on a specific port (SMTP)

Tags: python, sockets

I need to create a script with Python which checks if a list of users exist on the SMTP server (the list of IPs of servers is in a file).

This is the script I have run but I have an error in the socket connect function:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import sys
import os

with open("smtp_ip.txt", "r") as ip:
        for IpTested in ip :
                print IpTested
                s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                connect=s.connect(('IpTested', 25))
                banner=s.recv(1024)
                print "echec connect"
                with open("user.txt","r+") as username:
                        for user in username:
                                s.send('VRFY ' + user + '\r\n')
                                result=s.recv(1024)
                                print result
        s.close()       

ip.close()
```

and this is the error i have :

```
root@kali:~/smtppython# ./smtpv2.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./smtpv2.py", line 12, in <module>
    connect=s.connect(('IpTested', 25))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
connect=s.connect(('IpTested', 25))
```

you should have

```
connect=s.connect((IpTested, 25))
```

as the former passes the string `'IpTested'`, rather than the variable `IpTested`…

Also, you don't need

```
ip.close()
```

because the context manager (`with open("smtp_ip.txt", "r") as ip:`) takes care of it.

**Update:** and, since `IpTested` is a line read from a file, it contains a newline - you need to remove it, so:

```
connect = s.connect((IpTested.rstrip(), 25))
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your reply, i have already tried just with IpTested but still doesn’t work

Comment: Doesn't work… how? The same error as before? What was the last value printed by `print IpTested` before error?

Comment: i have the same Error,  even with the modification 


root@kali:~/smtppython# ./smtpv2.py 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./smtpv2.py", line 12, in <module>
    connect=s.connect((IpTested, 25))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Comment: I suggest checking if the first line in `smtp_ip.txt` is empty, and if so, removing it.

Comment: actualy the smtp_ip.txt contain IPs  for exemple(the first line is note empty) :

192.168.0.10
192.168.0.15
192.168.0.19
192.168.0.128
192.168.0.111
192.168.0.13

and the other file user.txt containe for exemple : 
bob
alice
mark
vincent...

Comment: i have just seen your update for connect = s.connect((IpTested.rstrip(), 25))

it is working now . 

thanks a lot

Comment: now i have another tipe of error: for exemple : 

192.168.0.200

550 5.1.1 admin... User unknown
500 5.5.1 Command unrecognized: ""

250 2.1.5 root <root@tophat.acme.com>
500 5.5.1 Command unrecognized: ""

550 5.1.1 kevin... User unknown
500 5.5.1 Command unrecognized: ""


192.168.0.10

501 5.5.4 Invalid Address

501 5.5.4 Invalid Address

501 5.5.4 Invalid Address

501 5.5.4 Invalid Address

192.168.0.15

550 5.1.1 <admin>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table
500 5.5.2 Error: bad syntax

252 2.0.0 root
500 5.5.2 Error: bad syntax

Comment: 192.168.0.23

502 Use HELO/EHLO first.

502 Use HELO/EHLO first.

502 Use HELO/EHLO first.


192.168.0.50

501 Syntax error at character position 10. CR and LF must be CRLF paired.  See RFC 2821 #2.7.1.

501 Syntax error at character position 9. CR and LF must be CRLF paired.  See RFC 2821 #2.7.1.

it seems like if i don't close the socket in the right moment

Comment: Indeed, `s.close()` should be inside the for loop (ie. same indent level as `s=`)

Comment: What problem? As far as I can see your script is now working.

Comment: actualy now the script is running but the VRFY for the second ip in not working i get : 501 5.5.4 Invalid Address while the normal return is : 250 2.1.5 root <email> or 550user unknown

Comment: it does not run for evry connect session a VRFY "user list"

Comment: it run just for the first ip, and for the rest of IPs they have another things in the parametre VRFY "user list".

i don't know if it is clear ?

Comment: Replace `s.send('VRFY ' + user + '\r\n')` with `s.send('VRFY ' + user.rstrip() + '\r\n')` - as it is, `user` contains a `\n` too.